# Excluding a directory and all subdirectories of it?

Tags: ant, jar, directory

I have a Java application that I am packaging into a JAR. I created an Ant script to do that as I need to also add resources to the JAR (icons etc).

Now, I have libraries that I use in my project (Apache HttpClient and a JSON library). I also copy their contents into the JAR, as it is the simplest way.

**My build file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar"
    name="Create Runnable Jar">
    <target name="create_run_jar">
        <jar destfile="C:/Users/Pietu1998/Documents/Java/Whatever.jar"
            filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class"
                    value="net.pietu1998.whatever" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="C:/Users/Pietu1998/Documents/Java/Whatever/bin"
                includes="*.class" />
            <fileset dir="C:/Users/Pietu1998/Documents/Java/Whatever/res" />
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/**"
                src="C:/Users/Pietu1998/Documents/Java/Whatever/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar" />
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/**"
                src="C:/Users/Pietu1998/Documents/Java/Whatever/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" />
            <!-- More (like 5) JARs -->
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

However, the libraries (JARs) have their own `META-INF` folders, and they have a lot of stuff in them; files like `LICENSE`, `CONDITIONS` and also a folder for Maven called `maven`.

The project is for personal use, so I just want to get rid of the unnecessary stuff. I have tried some ways to exclude all of the `META-INF` stuff, but something is always left behind.

1. `excludes="META-INF"` leaves everything.
2. `excludes="META-INF/**"` leaves the `maven` folder.
3. `**/excludes="META-INF/**"`, see above.

I believe I could use a lot of include-excludes or `patternset`s, but it would lead to a lot of repeating.

Is there a way **(not for this specific case)** to exclude a folder (`META-INF` here) and all its contents including subdirectories, and preferably with not too much repeating (for a lot of libraries)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it with the stars.

```xml
<zipfileset excludes="META-INF/**/*" src="C:\library.jar" />
```

This excludes the `META-INF` folder and all its contents.

- `*` means it excludes all files inside a folder, and
- `foo/**/bar` means it excludes `bar` in any level inside `foo`.

So, `foo/**/*` excludes every file on every level inside `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `excludes="META-INF/**""` works for me (Ant 1.9.3, Windows 7, JDK 1.7.0_51)
Some test after downloading original commons-logging-1.1.3.jar [from here](http://artfiles.org/apache.org//commons/logging/binaries/commons-logging-1.1.3-bin.zip) :

```
<project>

 <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/**" src="c:/area51/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" id="foobar"/>
  <!-- for output line by line -->
 <pathconvert property="foo" refid="foobar">
  <map from="c:/area51/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:" to="${line.separator}"/>
 </pathconvert>

  <echo>${foo}</echo>

</project>
```

output contains only classfiles under org/apache/commons/logging/.. :

```
[echo] commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/LogConfigurationException.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$1.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$2.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$3.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$4.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$5.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$6.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/LogSource.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/AvalonLogger.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Jdk13LumberjackLogger.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Jdk14Logger.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl$1.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl$2.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl$3.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogKitLogger.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/NoOpLog.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/ServletContextCleaner.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog$1.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable$1.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable$Entry.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable$Referenced.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable$WeakKey.class;
[echo] org/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable.class
```

**Maybe you forgot to set the update attribute from your jar task to true :**

```
<jar destfile=".." update="true" ..>
```

**to overwrite some already existing jarfile with the same name !?**